# Devolver un int como un string con C en SoloLearn

Tags: c

Para empezar desarrollar con Arduino intento devolver al apprentissage del C con SoloLearn sobre el teléfono. Sin embargo el código que escribí que no devuelve ningún error no devuelve cuando lo ejecuto:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int fibonacci(int n){
    int n0=0;
    int n1=0;
    int n2=0;
    for(int i=0;n;i++){
        n2 =n0 + n1;
        n0=n1;
        n1=n2;}
    return n2;
};

int main(){
    int res = 0;
    res = fibonacci(3);
    printf("¿que pasa?");
    printf("%c", res);
    return 0;
}
```

En efecto, me devuelve:

`No output`.

Comment: No sé si te refieres a imprimir res por pantalla, pero si es eso prueba con %d en vez de %c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tiene razón jesus_jbs. Y tambien el problema puede deberse al bucle:

```
for(int i=0;n;i++) {
```

En la condición estás solo evaluando n y como n no es 0, el bucle se ejecutará para siempre. Como el sistema de SoloLearn es para aprender, detendrá el bucle y no generará salida. En cambio si lo colocas asi:

```
for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {
```

El bucle solo se ejecutará hasta que i sea mayor o igual que n.